# transfer btc core wallet to electrum

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet, electrum

I am running a btc node and it is taking too long to sync. Is there any way to transfer the wallet to an electrum wallet? If so how?

1)Upgraded my btc node

2)Syncing

3)Transfer receiving addresses from btc to electrum

4)Whole amount from btc wallet does not match electrum wallet

5)About 15% difference

I am ready to shut down my btc node and save electricity.  Will I still be able to retrieve the lost bitcoins some time in the future.

I imagine a day where I could bring it to a place like Walmart or Best Buy to fix it.  Or Are there places you can bring it now?

Comment: Have you received funds to the bitcoin-core wallet already?

Comment: Yes, I've emptied out all the receiving addresses but it does not equal the total in the btc core wallet. It is less. Don't know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: ????????????????

Comment: Can you edit your post to include an order of events? How many times did you receive funds to the wallet made with bitcoin-core? Did you somehow send funds out of the bitcoin-core wallet in the past? Have you exported private keys from bitcoin-core and imported them to electrum? -- You could try running the command `bitcoin-cli listunspent` to see if there are any UTXOs still controlled by the wallet, but it may not return an accurate result if your node has not yet fully synced with the network

Comment: @requim: If you ever sent funds out of the wallet, some might be in a change address.

Comment: Change address? Can you explain that further? How would I find that address and private keys?